# Dye laminate which lost its color because of detergent

Tags: floor, varnishing, stain-removal

A bottle of detergent for toilets leaked on my laminate for 3 days.
The laminate became filled with it on a small area (less than 10cm²).
The floor lost its colors and it slightly tinted in blue (the detergent is blue).

[image]

What should I do to fix it?
Thanks

Comment: Is this real wood or a laminate that has a wood-like printed texture?  The cleaner has probably bleached away the stain or printing.  I think some of the confusion is "sprung floor" is a new one for a US English speaker.

Comment: @JPhi1618 It's laminate

Comment: If it's laminate, there is no real wood grain, or stain, or anything else.  It's a man-made printed surface that's most likely been permanently damaged by the cleaning chemicals in the toilet cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

most of the blue dyes in toilet cleaners are copper sulphate pentahydrate.  flushing the stain with dilute muriatic acid should re-dissolve it.  be gentle, wear gloves and a respirator, and keep the area small.  flush with water and baking soda immediately after you notice the stain is gone to stop the reaction from progressing too far.  seal afterwards with wax, acrylic, urethane, etc.

Comment: I should try. It is quite extreme but probably the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do anything.   If this is laminate it is simply a picture glued to material.

You jacked up the picture quality.  If you were a very skilled artist you could render out the picture again with paint and then poly over it.  If you were talented enough then it might look almost perfect.  But if you have this much artistic talent you should be painting something to sell and pay a couple hundred bucks for someone to lay down some new laminate.

Your fix = rug.